# Jquery-animating left to right absolutely positioned div

Tags: jquery, panel, jquery-animate, sliding

I have a hidden panel off the left side of the screen which slides into view on the click of a 'tab' positioned on the left side of the screen. I need the panel to slide over the top of the existing page content, and I need the tab to move with it.

This is an example of the original code which i have changed, how can I get the button/tab to slide as well?

http://www.iamkreative.co.uk/jquery/slideout_div.html

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reorganize your html and css... but try instead this-> http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/jquery/ or this http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/jquery/simple-slide-panel.html

First example is good for you imho. Should be easy to customize...